# Create a column that is a shift of the index in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in my DataFrame equal to the Index column but shifted 1 position upwards.

I know how to use the `shift` function to a columns that can be referred to in a df['column_name'] way, but I don't know how to do this with the index column.

I have tried `df.index.shift(-1)` but it doesn't work. `df['index_name'].shift(-1)` doesn't work either.

The desired result of would be to create a column which the index but shifted, just as if I did `df['column2'] = df['column1'].shift(-1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html), because `shift` is not implemented for some  `Index` like `RangeIndex` yet:

```
df["index_shifted"] = df.index.to_series().shift(-1)
```

If check [`Index.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html):

> Notes
>
> This method is only implemented for datetime-like index classes, i.e., **DatetimeIndex**, **PeriodIndex** and **TimedeltaIndex**.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
df["index_shifted"] = df.reset_index().iloc[:, 0].shift(-1)
```

The `reset_index` function put the index in the first column of the new DataFrame created and is selected by `iloc`. Then it is shifted backward by one step by the `shift` function.

> Documentation of these functions:
>
> [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
>
> [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
>
> [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

---

#### Don't use this

@Jezrael's answer is a better choice, because more efficient, especially for big Dataframes.